# Handling bad input in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem to invert the variable sum to float. The issue seems to be on the line next to `try` statement:

```
while True:    
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break 
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    continue
        print(fnum)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? There's no "right" thing to do here.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

The usage for `continue` is different in Python.

So basically you should remove line with `continue`:

```
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    finally:
        print(fnum)
```

Comment: there is  `finally`  in python https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: @AlbinPaul Good to know, thank you! I have updated my answer.